# Django Admin Custom Select box as per user in Admin

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have a model, which has User as Foreign Key. When I am viewing in the admin after login , showing all the user. I want to control it as per the user logged in the list should be displayed.

How can I achieve this so that if user1 login I can see different list and if user2 logs in different list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_form` method:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.fields['your_fk_field'].queryset = YourModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return form
```

Check this method in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form)